# What is the way to add migration before specific migration in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, migration

I have added new **migration** to change **column type**.
It worked well on my local.

But my team member have had the issue in migration since that **column** was not in **migration**.

It seems I had added that **column** manually in database.

To run **migration** without any issues for us(me and other team members), I want to **add migration to create new column before the migration to change column type**.

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Migration files have names like `20190616110000_create_foo.rb` and are applied in the native alphabetical order.

Simply rename files changing the timestamps according to the order you need.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another more proper way is in your migration (the change column type) you should add a condition to check if the column is there or not.

If it is already there (your local) then just change the column type. If it is not there (your colleagues local) then create a column with your desired type

```
if column_exists? :table_name, :column_name
  change_column :table_name, :column_name, :type
else
  add_column :table_name, :column_name, :type
end
```